Next js 14 POST request not working in production?
I am trugguling really hard with making a simple POST request from production.
It works locally, it fails in production, I dont understand why.
This is my POST request:
export async function POST(request: Request){
    console.log("calling post request!!!!")
    const data  = await req.json()
    console.log("POSTING SOME DATA: ", data)

    return NextResponse.json(data)
}

I am calling this request from api/email the following way:
export async function simplePost(data: FormData, setEmailSent, setError) {
  const apiEndpoint = '/api/email';

  const res = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
    })
  if(res.status === 200){
    setEmailSent(true);
  }else{
    setError(true);
  }
}

I am really frustrated, this is a simple, stupid post request, I can not understand why it doesnt work in production???
My folders look like this:

The error which I see on the console is page-198c25ba65ec6e90.js:1
POST https://my-website-on-production/api/email net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
﻿
I am in desperate need to make this work, please any help is highly appreciated!

Question, your route handler POST has a parameter named request but below you're referring to req, is this correct? Also, could you include the error response payload you're getting? Where is your application deployed?
